# enabling a UIButton to function through if/else statements in a log in

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, authentication, uibutton

i want to create a log in but makeing an IF statement whcih will give the UIButton - "LoginButton" functionality, if the input is correct, as stated in the code, please help build on the code -

```
#import "StudentLogInViewController.h"

@interface StudentLogInViewController ()

@end

@implementation StudentLogInViewController

-(IBAction)UsernametText {
LoginButton.userInteractionEnabled = [UsernameText.text isEqualToString:@"jzarate"];
}

-(IBAction)passwordText{
    LoginButton.userInteractionEnabled = [PasswordText.text isEqualToString:@"14054"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be remiss if I didn't mention that enabling a login button only when the correct username and passwords are entered is probably not the best idea from a security standpoint. However, if that is what you want to do:

// StudentLogInViewController.h

```
// Conform the UITextFieldDelegate
@interface StudentLogInViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

// StudentLogInViewController.m

```
#import "StudentLogInViewController.h"

@interface StudentLogInViewController () 

@end

@implementation StudentLogInViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UsernameText.delegate = self;
    PasswordText.delegate = self;
}

// This is a UITextFieldDelegate method
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // The text field will not be updated to the newest text yet, but we know what the user just did so get it into a string
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    // Depending on which field the user is typing in, load in the appropriate inputs
    NSString *username, *password;
    if (textField == UsernameField) {
        username = newString;
        password = PasswordField.text;
    } else {
        username = UsernameField.text;
        password = newString;
    }

    // If both the username and password are correct then enable the button
    LoginButton.enabled = ([username isEqualToString:@"correctUsername"] && [password isEqualToString:@"correctPassword"]);

    // Return YES so that the user's edits are used
    return YES;
}

@end
```